# TinyMCE escapes some especial characters

Tags: tinymce

When, for example, I write this HTML with tinyMCE:

```
<p>asdasd</p>
<p class="relevant">asd</p>
<p>as</p>
```

the php that receives the form post prints the next:

```
<p>asdasd</p>
<p class=\"relevant\">asd</p>
<p>as</p>
```

How can turn off this behavior?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you inserting your HTML directly into TinyMCE or into the HTML Source Editor of TinyMCE?

Comment: In fact, I'm not inserting the html. What I mean is that it was the html generated by my writing into tinyMCE, as it can be seen by the html source viewer button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely due to the MagicQuotes feature in PHP and is covered in the [TinyMCE FAQ](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE_FAQ#HTML_output_include_lots_of_.5C.22_like_.3Ca_href.3D.5C.22mylink.htm.5C.22.3Elink.3C.2Fa.3E.3F).

The simplest way to deal with this is to disable the feature, especially as it has been deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0

An alternative is to clean up the results using

```
stripslashes($_POST['text']);
```

Comment: stripslashes works perfectly, but probably I will disable MagicQuotes.  Thank you!